# Python Pandas datetime or timestamp?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Thanks for your patience. This might be a beginner question; I am having trouble with Pandas' date formats. I am new to Python Pandas; I read dates in str format into a dataframe via:

```
rev = pd.read_csv('review.csv', encoding='cp1252')
rev['rev_date'] = [pd.to_datetime(date) for date in rev['rev_date']]

print(type(rev['rev_date'])) #<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
print(type(rev.rev_date[0])) #<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

Now if I try to extract the year from rev via:

```
rev['yr'] = rev['rev_date'].map(lambda t: t.date())
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'date'
```

If rev_date is a Timestamp, why do I get the above error?

EDIT:

```
rev['yr'] = rev['rev_date'].map(lambda t: t.year)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'year'
```

I don't get why rev_date would be a str when type shows it to be a Timestamp

Comment: Why are you trying to extract the year by using `t.date()` instead of `t.year`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Can you provide a self-contained example with sample data?

Comment: @BrenBarn - that absolutely helped. Thank You. If I had been patient enough to explore the date column in the csv file, I'd have noticed it had a few garbage values. Two hours ago! Please close out the question. Thanks!

Comment: Some other remarks: 1) you don't need to loop over the values to use `to_datetime`, just provide the column at once: `rev['rev_date'] = pd.to_datetime(rev['rev_date'])`, and 2) you can use the `.dt` accessor instead of the `map` function: `rev['rev_date'].dt.year`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed garbage values in the CSV file which was causing the exception.

Was also able to add commnents from joris. Thanks!